# Is there a way to store image from the google storage buckets as JPEG locally?

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-platform, jpeg

So currently I have images stored in gcp storage.
When I fetch an image, I receive a File object with several parameters. Being one of them `mediaLink` with a format like `https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/{path}%{image_name}?generation={value}&alt=media`
The problem is that this url is only accessasble with permission, I want to be able to save the image as a JPEG so I can later send it to the user via email.

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If your bucket is not public, you always need authentication to access to it. Else make it public (at your own risk!)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere well if the bucket is private and I cannot make it public, isn't there a way to replicate the photo somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can use gsutil to copy the blob from the bucket to another one, or to your computer. You can also use code and APIs/client libraries.

Answer (score 0):

To grant access to a object on Cloud Storage for an user without change the bucket to public or require user authentication you may use Signed URLs. With a Signed URl you will be able to share a temporary link to get or upload a file.

More info about [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)